# Why my named pipe input command line just hangs when it is called?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pipe, named-pipes

#### Why my named pipe input command line just hangs when it is called?

Based on the answers:

1. [Writing to stdin of background process](https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process)
2. [Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314451/accessing-bash-command-line-args-vs)
3. [Send command to a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998126/send-command-to-a-background-process/41960112)
4. [Can I redirect output to a log file and background a process at the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74520/can-i-redirect-output-to-a-log-file-and-background-a-process-at-the-same-time)

I wrote two shell scripts to communicate with my game server. And worked the first time I did it. Since it them they do not work anymore. Every time I do `./send.sh commands` the command line hangs until I hit `Ctrl+C`.

It also hangs and does nothing when I do directly `echo commamd > /tmp/srv-input`

---

## The scripts

It does start the server and configure it to read/receive my commands while it run in background:

**start_czero_server.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Go to the game server application folder where the game application `hlds_run` is
cd /home/user/Half-Life
pkill -f hlds

# Set up a pipe named `/tmp/srv-input`
rm /tmp/srv-input
mkfifo /tmp/srv-input

cat > /tmp/srv-input &
echo $! > /tmp/srv-input-cat-pid

# Start the server reading from the pipe named `/tmp/srv-input`
# And also output all its console to the file `/home/user/Half-Life/my_logs.txt`
cat /tmp/srv-input | ./hlds_run -console -game czero +port 27015 > my_logs.txt 2>&1 &

# Successful execution 
exit 0
```

---

This second script it just a wrapper which allow me easily to send commands to the my server:

**send.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$@" > /tmp/srv-input

# Successful execution 
exit 0
```

Now every time I want to send a command to my server I just do on the terminal:

```
./send.sh mp_timelimit 30
```

---

I always keep another open terminal open just to listen to my server server console. To do it just use the `tail` command with the `-f` flag to follow my server console output:

```
./tail -f /home/user/Half-Life/my_logs.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off just having `hlds_run` read directly from the pipe instead of having `cat` pipe it in.

Try

```
./hlds_run … > my_logs.txt 2>&1 < /tmp/srv-input &
```

Instead of

```
cat /tmp/srv-input | ./hlds_run …
```